# Can't get mouse coordinates through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I have been trying to get a grasp of javascript. I've been experimenting through the past couple of months with different code to see what all is possible through javascript. Recently I've been trying to find various ways to capture the mouse coordinates through javascript with a canvas. Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/f8n2one4/

As you can see, there's a MouseHandler which is supposed to capture the mouse coordinates through the ClientX and ClientY variables. However, when I try to display these variables, nothing comes up. Why is that?

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "x: " + x + " y: " + y;
```

Shouldn't it show the x and y values?

Comment: where do you fill this x and y with the mousepointer's values?

Comment: http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html take a look at this, it might help you.

Comment: Can't you see: `1000(index):104 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
1623 console messages are not shown.
613(index):104 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` in console?

Comment: How did you access that Kumar? When I do inspect element and attempt to go to the console, I don't see it! (Google Chrome)

Comment: Google Chrome here. Call me **Praveen**. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8n2one4/3/ Use `F12`.

Comment: @RichardSherd Also, you are testing the patience of the browser man. Please make sure you don't call the `setInterval` that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example are you are initializing the mouse handler (with `MouseHandler.init(element)`) but the `x` and `y` values have to be accessed using the `getPos()` method:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
    "x: " + MouseHandler.getPos().x + 
    " y: " + MouseHandler.getPos().y;
```

You can see a working update to your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8n2one4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The x and y variable are out of the scope of your draw() method.

try the following:

```
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player();
    MouseHandler.init(document);
    var clientPosition = MouseHandler.getPos();
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "x: " + clientPosition.x + " y: " + clientPosition.y;   
}
```

See it working here.

I would recommend not to initialize the whole MouseHandler every interval, just getting the position on every interval.

Also if you are animating use .requestanimationframe() instead of setInterval, you'll get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` and `y` do not exist. You need to use:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "x: " + MouseHandler.getPos().x + " y: " + MouseHandler.getPos().y;
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8n2one4/3/**

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really simple, your x, y are out of scope.

You could access them via your MouseHandler variable :

```
MouseHandler.getPos().x
MouseHandler.getPos().y
```

Or try OOP Javascript and instantiating the MouseHandler with a 'new' operator

```
var MouseHandler = function() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

var myMouseHandler = new MouseHandler();

console.log(myMouseHandler.x + myMouseHandler.y);
```